# How to recieve a Direct Method on the ESP32 with azure-sdk-for-c-arduino

Tags: esp32, azure-iot-hub

For a school project I am using IoT Hub to connect between different devices (ESP32), The intention is to use a web application to retrieve data from a device. I want to do this by using a Direct Method.

Now I have seen in the past some direct methods using python and how I can use this in Azure Functions but not yet on an ESP32. By the way, I am programming in C on the ESP32.

Does anyone have an example code for this? I am not finding really much info about direct methods in C with the library "azure-sdk-for-c-arduino".

Thanks in advance

My code at the moment (This is test code):

```
// Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

/*
   This is an Arduino-based Azure IoT Hub sample for ESPRESSIF ESP32 boards.
   It uses our Azure Embedded SDK for C to help interact with Azure IoT.
   For reference, please visit https://github.com/azure/azure-sdk-for-c.

   To connect and work with Azure IoT Hub you need an MQTT client, connecting, subscribing
   and publishing to specific topics to use the messaging features of the hub.
   Our azure-sdk-for-c is an MQTT client support library, helping composing and parsing the
   MQTT topic names and messages exchanged with the Azure IoT Hub.

   This sample performs the following tasks:
   - Synchronize the device clock with a NTP server;
   - Initialize our "az_iot_hub_client" (struct for data, part of our azure-sdk-for-c);
   - Initialize the MQTT client (here we use ESPRESSIF's esp_mqtt_client, which also handle the tcp connection and TLS);
   - Connect the MQTT client (using server-certificate validation, SAS-tokens for client authentication);
   - Periodically send telemetry data to the Azure IoT Hub.

   To properly connect to your Azure IoT Hub, please fill the information in the `iot_configs.h` file.
*/

//Variabeles for drukknop
const int PushButton = 35;

//Variables for weight sensor;
double weight = 5.0;

// C99 libraries
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

// Libraries for MQTT client and WiFi connection
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <mqtt_client.h>

// Azure IoT SDK for C includes
#include <az_core.h>
#include <az_iot.h>
#include <azure_ca.h>

// Libraries for SendingJson
#include <ArduinoJson.h>

// Additional sample headers
#include "AzIoTSasToken.h"
#include "SerialLogger.h"
#include "iot_configs.h"

// When developing for your own Arduino-based platform,
// please follow the format '(ard;<platform>)'.
#define AZURE_SDK_CLIENT_USER_AGENT "c/" AZ_SDK_VERSION_STRING "(ard;esp32)"

// Utility macros and defines
#define sizeofarray(a) (sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]))
#define NTP_SERVERS "pool.ntp.org", "time.nist.gov"
#define MQTT_QOS1 1
#define DO_NOT_RETAIN_MSG 0
#define SAS_TOKEN_DURATION_IN_MINUTES 60
#define UNIX_TIME_NOV_13_2017 1510592825

#define PST_TIME_ZONE -8
#define PST_TIME_ZONE_DAYLIGHT_SAVINGS_DIFF   1

#define GMT_OFFSET_SECS (PST_TIME_ZONE * 3600)
#define GMT_OFFSET_SECS_DST ((PST_TIME_ZONE + PST_TIME_ZONE_DAYLIGHT_SAVINGS_DIFF) * 3600)

// Translate iot_configs.h defines into variables used by the sample
static const char* ssid = IOT_CONFIG_WIFI_SSID;
static const char* password = IOT_CONFIG_WIFI_PASSWORD;
static const char* host = IOT_CONFIG_IOTHUB_FQDN;
static const char* mqtt_broker_uri = "mqtts://" IOT_CONFIG_IOTHUB_FQDN;
static const char* device_id = IOT_CONFIG_DEVICE_ID;
static const int mqtt_port = AZ_IOT_DEFAULT_MQTT_CONNECT_PORT;

// Memory allocated for the sample's variables and structures.
static esp_mqtt_client_handle_t mqtt_client;
static az_iot_hub_client client;

static char mqtt_client_id[128];
static char mqtt_username[128];
static char mqtt_password[200];
static uint8_t sas_signature_buffer[256];
static unsigned long next_telemetry_send_time_ms = 0;
static char telemetry_topic[128];
static uint8_t telemetry_payload[100];
static uint32_t telemetry_send_count = 0;

#define INCOMING_DATA_BUFFER_SIZE 128
static char incoming_data[INCOMING_DATA_BUFFER_SIZE];

// Auxiliary functions
#ifndef IOT_CONFIG_USE_X509_CERT
static AzIoTSasToken sasToken(
  &client,
  AZ_SPAN_FROM_STR(IOT_CONFIG_DEVICE_KEY),
  AZ_SPAN_FROM_BUFFER(sas_signature_buffer),
  AZ_SPAN_FROM_BUFFER(mqtt_password));
#endif // IOT_CONFIG_USE_X509_CERT

static void connectToWiFi()
{
  Logger.Info("Connecting to WIFI SSID " + String(ssid));

  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED)
  {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }

  Serial.println("");

  Logger.Info("WiFi connected, IP address: " + WiFi.localIP().toString());
}

static void initializeTime()
{
  Logger.Info("Setting time using SNTP");

  configTime(GMT_OFFSET_SECS, GMT_OFFSET_SECS_DST, NTP_SERVERS);
  time_t now = time(NULL);
  while (now < UNIX_TIME_NOV_13_2017)
  {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
    now = time(nullptr);
  }
  Serial.println("");
  Logger.Info("Time initialized!");
}

void receivedCallback(char* topic, byte* payload, unsigned int length)
{
  Logger.Info("Received [");
  Logger.Info(topic);
  Logger.Info("]: ");
  for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
  {
    Serial.print((char)payload[i]);
  }
  Serial.println("");
}

static esp_err_t mqtt_event_handler(esp_mqtt_event_handle_t event)
{
  switch (event->event_id)
  {
      int i, r;

    case MQTT_EVENT_ERROR:
      Logger.Info("MQTT event MQTT_EVENT_ERROR");
      break;
    case MQTT_EVENT_CONNECTED:
      Logger.Info("MQTT event MQTT_EVENT_CONNECTED");

      r = esp_mqtt_client_subscribe(mqtt_client, AZ_IOT_HUB_CLIENT_C2D_SUBSCRIBE_TOPIC, 1);
      if (r == -1)
      {
        Logger.Error("Could not subscribe for cloud-to-device messages.");
      }
      else
      {
        Logger.Info("Subscribed for cloud-to-device messages; message id:"  + String(r));
      }

      break;
    case MQTT_EVENT_DISCONNECTED:
      Logger.Info("MQTT event MQTT_EVENT_DISCONNECTED");
      break;
    case MQTT_EVENT_SUBSCRIBED:
      Logger.Info("MQTT event MQTT_EVENT_SUBSCRIBED");
      break;
    case MQTT_EVENT_UNSUBSCRIBED:
      Logger.Info("MQTT event MQTT_EVENT_UNSUBSCRIBED");
      break;
    case MQTT_EVENT_PUBLISHED:
      Logger.Info("MQTT event MQTT_EVENT_PUBLISHED");
      break;
    case MQTT_EVENT_DATA:
      Logger.Info("MQTT event MQTT_EVENT_DATA");

      for (i = 0; i < (INCOMING_DATA_BUFFER_SIZE - 1) && i < event->topic_len; i++)
      {
        incoming_data[i] = event->topic[i];
      }
      incoming_data[i] = '\0';
      Logger.Info("Topic: " + String(incoming_data));

      for (i = 0; i < (INCOMING_DATA_BUFFER_SIZE - 1) && i < event->data_len; i++)
      {
        incoming_data[i] = event->data[i];
      }
      incoming_data[i] = '\0';
      if (String(incoming_data) == "GETWEIGHT")
      {
        Logger.Info("Send Data To The Cloud ");
        sendTelemetry();
      }
      else
      {
          Logger.Info("Data: " + String(incoming_data));
      }

      break;
    case MQTT_EVENT_BEFORE_CONNECT:
      Logger.Info("MQTT event MQTT_EVENT_BEFORE_CONNECT");
      break;
    default:
      Logger.Error("MQTT event UNKNOWN");
      break;
  }

  return ESP_OK;
}

static void initializeIoTHubClient()
{
  az_iot_hub_client_options options = az_iot_hub_client_options_default();
  options.user_agent = AZ_SPAN_FROM_STR(AZURE_SDK_CLIENT_USER_AGENT);

  if (az_result_failed(az_iot_hub_client_init(
                         &client,
                         az_span_create((uint8_t*)host, strlen(host)),
                         az_span_create((uint8_t*)device_id, strlen(device_id)),
                         &options)))
  {
    Logger.Error("Failed initializing Azure IoT Hub client");
    return;
  }

  size_t client_id_length;
  if (az_result_failed(az_iot_hub_client_get_client_id(
                         &client, mqtt_client_id, sizeof(mqtt_client_id) - 1, &client_id_length)))
  {
    Logger.Error("Failed getting client id");
    return;
  }

  if (az_result_failed(az_iot_hub_client_get_user_name(
                         &client, mqtt_username, sizeofarray(mqtt_username), NULL)))
  {
    Logger.Error("Failed to get MQTT clientId, return code");
    return;
  }

  Logger.Info("Client ID: " + String(mqtt_client_id));
  Logger.Info("Username: " + String(mqtt_username));
}

static int initializeMqttClient()
{
#ifndef IOT_CONFIG_USE_X509_CERT
  if (sasToken.Generate(SAS_TOKEN_DURATION_IN_MINUTES) != 0)
  {
    Logger.Error("Failed generating SAS token");
    return 1;
  }
#endif

  esp_mqtt_client_config_t mqtt_config;
  memset(&mqtt_config, 0, sizeof(mqtt_config));
  mqtt_config.uri = mqtt_broker_uri;
  mqtt_config.port = mqtt_port;
  mqtt_config.client_id = mqtt_client_id;
  mqtt_config.username = mqtt_username;

#ifdef IOT_CONFIG_USE_X509_CERT
  Logger.Info("MQTT client using X509 Certificate authentication");
  mqtt_config.client_cert_pem = IOT_CONFIG_DEVICE_CERT;
  mqtt_config.client_key_pem = IOT_CONFIG_DEVICE_CERT_PRIVATE_KEY;
#else // Using SAS key
  mqtt_config.password = (const char*)az_span_ptr(sasToken.Get());
#endif

  mqtt_config.keepalive = 30;
  mqtt_config.disable_clean_session = 0;
  mqtt_config.disable_auto_reconnect = false;
  mqtt_config.event_handle = mqtt_event_handler;
  mqtt_config.user_context = NULL;
  mqtt_config.cert_pem = (const char*)ca_pem;

  mqtt_client = esp_mqtt_client_init(&mqtt_config);

  if (mqtt_client == NULL)
  {
    Logger.Error("Failed creating mqtt client");
    return 1;
  }

  esp_err_t start_result = esp_mqtt_client_start(mqtt_client);

  if (start_result != ESP_OK)
  {
    Logger.Error("Could not start mqtt client; error code:" + start_result);
    return 1;
  }
  else
  {
    Logger.Info("MQTT client started");
    return 0;
  }
}

/*
   @brief           Gets the number of seconds since UNIX epoch until now.
   @return uint32_t Number of seconds.
*/
static uint32_t getEpochTimeInSecs()
{
  return (uint32_t)time(NULL);
}

static void establishConnection()
{
  connectToWiFi();
  initializeTime();
  initializeIoTHubClient();
  (void)initializeMqttClient();
}

static void getTelemetryPayload(az_span payload, az_span* out_payload)
{
  az_span original_payload = payload;

  payload = az_span_copy(
              payload, AZ_SPAN_FROM_STR("{ \"deviceId\": "));
  payload = az_span_copy(payload, AZ_SPAN_FROM_STR( IOT_CONFIG_DEVICE_ID )); 
  payload = az_span_copy(payload, AZ_SPAN_FROM_STR( "," ));
  payload = az_span_copy(payload, AZ_SPAN_FROM_STR( "\" weight\": "));
  (void)az_span_u32toa(payload, weight , &payload);
  payload = az_span_copy(payload, AZ_SPAN_FROM_STR(" }"));
  payload = az_span_copy_u8(payload, '\0');

  *out_payload = az_span_slice(original_payload, 0, az_span_size(original_payload) - az_span_size(payload) - 1);
}

static void sendTelemetry()
{
  az_span telemetry = AZ_SPAN_FROM_BUFFER(telemetry_payload);

  Logger.Info("Sending telemetry ...");

  // The topic could be obtained just once during setup,
  // however if properties are used the topic need to be generated again to reflect the
  // current values of the properties.
  if (az_result_failed(az_iot_hub_client_telemetry_get_publish_topic(
                         &client, NULL, telemetry_topic, sizeof(telemetry_topic), NULL)))
  {
    Logger.Error("Failed az_iot_hub_client_telemetry_get_publish_topic");
    return;
  }

  getTelemetryPayload(telemetry, &telemetry);

  if (esp_mqtt_client_publish(
        mqtt_client,
        telemetry_topic,
        (const char*)az_span_ptr(telemetry),
        az_span_size(telemetry),
        MQTT_QOS1,
        DO_NOT_RETAIN_MSG)
      == 0)
  {
    Logger.Error("Failed publishing");
  }
  else
  {
    Logger.Info("Message published successfully");
  }
}


// Arduino setup and loop main functions.

void setup()
{
  establishConnection();
  pinMode(PushButton, INPUT);
}

void loop()
{
  if (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED)
  {
    connectToWiFi();
  }
#ifndef IOT_CONFIG_USE_X509_CERT
  else if (sasToken.IsExpired())
  {
    Logger.Info("SAS token expired; reconnecting with a new one.");
    (void)esp_mqtt_client_destroy(mqtt_client);
    initializeMqttClient();
  }
#endif
  int Push_button_state = digitalRead(PushButton);
  // if condition checks if push button is pressed
  if ( Push_button_state == HIGH )
  {
    Serial.println("De Button Is ingedrukt");
    sendTelemetry();
    delay(500);
  }
}
```

The idea is that when I send a Direct Method "GETWEIGHT" I get a json value back.

Answer (score 2):

In your `initializeMqttClient` method, you can add the following line.

```c
  mqtt_client.setCallback(receivedCallback);
```

Your `receivedCallback` method can have the following definition (code from a Microsoft [sample](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-c-arduino/blob/bd5b9ea615abefbc61df89d64742ab6af6dd7265/examples/Azure_IoT_Hub_ESP32/Azure_IoT_Hub_ESP32.ino#L127))

```c
void receivedCallback(char* topic, byte* payload, unsigned int length)
{
  Logger.Info("Received [");
  Logger.Info(topic);
  Logger.Info("]: ");
  for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
  {
    Serial.print((char)payload[i]);
  }
  Serial.println("");
}
```

You mentioned you want to retrieve data from the device, so you probably want to respond to the message. This is done by sending a message on the right topic. You need to include the status (for instance a 200 indicating 'OK') and the ID of the direct method. This id is included when you receive the direct method. For instance, if you receive a direct method with ID 42, you can respond to it by publishing:

```c
void RespondToDirectMethod()
{
  mqtt_client.publish("$iothub/methods/res/200/?$rid=42", "", false);
}
```

Comment: Based on the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-mqtt-support#respond-to-a-direct-method, the respond topic should be *$iothub/methods/res/{status}/?$rid={request id}*, so in your example the topic will be *$iothub/methods/res/200/?$rid=42*

Comment: Thanks, Roman, I edited that part of the answer.

Comment: @MatthijsvanderVeer Thanks for explaining. I added " mqtt_client.setCallback(receivedCallback);" add the end of the function and I am getting this error: "request for member 'setCallback' in 'mqtt_client', which is of pointer type 'esp_mqtt_client_handle_t {aka esp_mqtt_client*}' (maybe you meant to use '->' ?). ". Am I looking over something?

Comment: @RomanKiss Do you maybe what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In your `mqtt_event_handler`

you subscribed to `AZ_IOT_HUB_CLIENT_C2D_SUBSCRIBE_TOPIC`
if you want to use a direct method, change to `AZ_IOT_HUB_CLIENT_METHODS_SUBSCRIBE_TOPIC`

Comment: or you can just subscribed both